# Fading the background of page and playing animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael

I have a html page in which I made some animations with the vectors drawn on a `Raphael` canvas using the `Raphael JS` library. So, here's the scenario in which I am facing a bit of confusion.

At the initial point, there needs to be a circle on my html page, with a click event handler. Clicking on the circle should fade out the rest of the page and play some animations with the circle. I can play the animations for now, but how do I fade the rest part of the such that only the circle and its animation come out highlighted on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create overlay DIV with 100% width and height, z-index above rest of the page and display:none property (in this overlay div you will have canvas)
2. On circle click event use jquery $("#overlayDiv").fadeIn()
3. Now do dirty things you were trying to do with animation.

Comment: That means the animations should be done by creating another canvas over this new `div`? For e.g.: I am trying to move this circle in the animation but if I create a new canvas over the `div`, the previous circle will be visible beneath the faded background.

Comment: Then create , three layers. rest of the page say z-index:1. Overlay Div z-index : 2 which you fade in when circle clicked. And, canvas on top i.e z-index:3. Notice that, You should not put Canvas inside overlay DIV because when you fadeIn and fade Out, your canvas also will appear and disappear. OverlayDiv should also have css property of 100% width and height, display:none, color:white. Since, initially you want it to hide and when circle clicked use .fadeIn() jquery to change it's property display:none to display: block

Comment: @ashish: There are going to be other things on the canvas as well that will be drawn. I have to highlight one particular at a time, so I can't make the wholw canvas visible.

Comment: Sorry Dude, but I can't write whole code for you. Inside canvas what to display what to not is determined by animation programmed by javascript and if you have someknowledge about JS/Jquery and canvas then you can do it. Otherwise, read some books first.